# Error. Your card doesn't support automatic recurring payments-Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mastercard

When I'm trying to authenticate my card with Google cloud I'm getting this error.

> Your card doesn't support automatic recurring payments [QR-CC3ST-02].

I got my otp and I had successfully authenticated.

I also got message from my bank saying that my authentication is successful.

Still Google is keep saying above error.

Now my card isn't verified.

I contacted the bank and they said no error from their side.

I also tried with an other card too, but still getting this error.

What would  be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: just read an article, where it was suggested to pay once manually and to remove the card, in order to attempt adding it later again. also found another relevant article: https://www.cardfellow.com/blog/credit-card-processing-guide/

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the country and the regulations on financial transactions, some type of cards does not support Recurring Payments. Most debit cards do not work. Credit cards are supposed to work. Get in touch with your bank regarding the details.

For example, [Indian debit cards](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3401127?hl=en) do not usually work due to certain regulations.

<s>A workaround could be to use the '[Pay early](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6220303?hl=en)' option</s>

Comment: they are not clear as well, on one tab they are showing gcp bill and on other showing remaining free trial balance

Comment: hi, where do i find the card network API's to integrate with my backend? Can these be found online or do i need to contact an acquiring bank first and they will provide me with the necessary API's?

Comment: Contact your bank, send a printscreen of the error message. This is a recent error and some regulations might have changed. I face same issue with HDFC credit card for last 15 days and it did not give the error before 15 days.

Comment: We can do the payment manually within the due period

Answer (score 5):

Recent update On Google Payments for Google Cloud. They won't accept indian debit cards due to 3D verification issue.

> https://support.google.com/a/answer/3401127?hl=en

Comment: so is there any workaround?

Comment: hi, where do i find the card network API's to integrate with my backend? Can these be found online or do i need to contact an acquiring bank first and they will provide me with the necessary API's?

Answer (score -1):

according to the [Google Public Document](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods):

Google Cloud accept debit cards with the Visa or MasterCard logo.
Prepaid cards and Virtual Credit Cards (VCCs) are not accepted for payment.

Depending on the Google product or service, your recurring payments fall into one of four categories.

**Automatic payments**: When you owe a certain amount of money, your payment method is automatically charged.

**Automatic monthly payments**: Your payment method is charged at the same time every month.

**Manual payments**: You can pay a fee in advance for a product or service you’ll get or use later.

**Monthly invoicing**: After you get your monthly invoice, you pay the bill within a set amount of time.

You can contact the [Google payments center](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6220303?hl=en) for more informations.

Answer (score -2):

If you're registering for the first time and just want to use the free tier, just dismiss the message and close the popup. Your $300 credit and free usage should still work.

Comment: No, it will not work. You can't create an instance without clearing it.

Comment: same here. i am also not able to create or start intances!!

Comment: same here. Not able to use it

Comment: I'm not able to deploy any code as my payment method is not verified because of this exact error message.