# How to create the bucket and deploy application on Google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am trying to use google cloud platform, I want to create a bucket on google cloud storage. I searched a lot on the same but no luck. please anyone can help me to create a bucket on google cloud storage without filling the billing details?

And also want to deploy my application on the google cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't really use GCP without providing the billing details. However, your billing details are used solely for verification (against bots) during your trial period.

**You won't be charged after your trial unless you upgrade to the paid plan.** If you use the 300$ credit or the trial ends after 12 months, all running services will be stopped and your data will be available for 30 more days (except those stored on Compute Engine).

If you don't want to add your credit card, there is also an option to provide bank account information. You can see it here under [No Credit Card?](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#credit_card_verification).

See this page for more info:
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

Comment: Thanks to your Answer, I was filling the billing details but I got a popup which had a message, **Something Went Wrong, Your card does not support automatic recurring payments.**

Comment: Check this thread regarding debit/credit cards https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588424/error-your-card-doesnt-support-automatic-recurring-payments-google-cloud