# Cant Upgrade to Firebase Blaze Plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to upgrade to Firebase Blaze plan. I have used multiple bank cards Debit/Credit as well. But I have been getting the same error:

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-CC3ST-04]
```

I have googled this error as well, but nobody seems to get this exact error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally Resolved this Issue, I had a word with the customer care at `Google` there was some glitch on their side and it can only be resolved on their end.
Secondly people in India face Issue with the requirement of recurring payments, and cards in India do support such payments, but `Google` is not available in majority of banks to be selected as an institution that has the privilege of making Monthly debits from your account, This Issue was also resolved by getting in-touch with the customer support.
 The Customer Support with google is Phenomenal!! they will solve every issue with any of their products on phone or on mail.

Comment: How do you get in touch with Google support if you can't complete setting up billing account and have no access to support?

Comment: @Xualakhawlhring you can mail them on firebase-support@google.com

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would be to contact the firebase support.

https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

as I saw, that is a common issue with Indian debit / credit card.

check also [Error. Your card doesn't support automatic recurring payments-Google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588424/error-your-card-doesnt-support-automatic-recurring-payments-google-cloud)

Comment: Thanks for sharing , I have written to Firebase, Ill update once I do get a resolution!

Comment: Any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

One of my friend was facing the same problem.
Follow these steps -

- choose account type individual
- enter your card details
- In the tax status option, select as unregistered individual.
- Submit the request (in my case I didn’t add my pan details)

This worked for me, see if this works for you as well.